# Spring Security UI - Cannot open register/forgot password page

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I have put the `":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"` into my `BuildConfig` and compiled it then I created the `auth, register and securityInfo` views and controller by using the spring ui command. I also put a user in my db to test it.

However, when I tested it I just get to the login page, after login in I get to the grails page back. However the button `Register New User and Forgotten Passoword` do not work, I only get redirected to the `login` page! Even though the file gets correctly rendered to `*.html`.

This is how the view structure looks like:

[image]

My `ÙRLMappings` look like that:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your answer on my problem!

**UPDATE**
This is my `auth.gsp`:

```
<html>

<head>
<title><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.title'/></title>
<meta name='layout' content='register'/>
</head>

<body>

<p/>

<div class="login s2ui_center ui-corner-all" style='text-align:center;'>
    <div class="login-inner">
    <form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id="loginForm" name="loginForm" autocomplete='off'>
    <div class="sign-in">

    <h1><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.signin'/></h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username"><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.username'/></label></td>
            <td><input name="j_username" id="username" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password"><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.password'/></label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="password" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="${rememberMeParameter}" id="remember_me" checked="checked" />
                <label for='remember_me'><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.rememberme'/></label> |
                <span class="forgot-link">
                    <g:link controller='register' action='forgotPassword'><g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.forgotPassword'/></g:link>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <s2ui:linkButton elementId='register' controller='register' messageCode='spring.security.ui.login.register'/>
                <s2ui:submitButton elementId='loginButton' form='loginForm' messageCode='spring.security.ui.login.login'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').focus();
});

<s2ui:initCheckboxes/>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess would be you have set your register and forgot password pages as requiring  authentication in your annotations or request map

Comment: When you try to register do you get error messages ?

Comment: @daguru Thx for your answer! No, I get no stacktrace and no error page at all back...

Comment: @tim_yates Thx for your answer! I have changed nothing on the RequestMap. My register and forgotten password page are the pages generated by `spring ui`. There are also no Configurations in my `Config.groovy` file. What should I add to my file? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add the following two rules in your `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`. It is in the `Config.groovy` file.

```
'/register/index':                ['permitAll'],
'/register/forgotPassword':       ['permitAll'],
```

Otherwise, the spring security will bump your request back to the login/auth screen.

Comment: may also need '/register/register': ['permitAll'],
'/register/verifyRegistration': ['permitAll'], '/register/resetPassword': ['permitAll'] to access the actions

Answer (score 1):

What about your controllers ?? I hear no mention of them you including them in your config file.
 Define your success handler and define a controller for successful login.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/homePage'
```

Then if you already are being logged in then set access into the controllers using security annotations or using `InterceptMapURL`. 

Looking at your problem you just haven't configured the security plugin well that's it. Well look at some other spring security implementation for grails in github, I think that will help you.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However my problem is not that I cannot login, my problem is that on my rendered html pages the two links to the register and to the forgotten password page do not work!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add anonymous role to your RegisterController

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

@Secured(['ROLE_ANONYMOUS'])
class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
}
```